# Using a literal string in SELECT statement

Tags: soql

Is there an equivalent SOQL syntax to write following SQL?

```
SELECT Id, 'Northwind Category' AS Note
FROM categories
```

Comment: why would you want to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, we can't provide a literal string. SOQL only accepts fields and a few select formulas in the *fields* section of a query. This includes aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN), toLabel, and TYPEOF (in some cases). If you wanted to include a literal value, you'd have to make a formula and select it as a field.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the Case function to get around this. This is not the standard use - but if you really need it then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT Id,
CASE
    WHEN ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Northwind Category'
    ELSE 'Northwind Category'
END AS Note
FROM categories
```

Alternatively when creating a data extension set a default value.

Comment: This does not seem to be a SOQL.

Comment: Still works in the query studio

Comment: The query studio is part of the marketing cloud, which uses queries similar to SQL, this question is about SOQL.